# Mute WebViewer in Windows Mixer

Tags: vb.net, webview, webview2, windows-core-audio

I'm developing a project with WebViewer using vb.net. I would like to know if there is any way to create a button that when clicked silences only the volume mixer (windows system) on [Microsoft Edge WebViewer2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)?

I tried to use Core Audio.NET but it lowers all the main volume.

[A snapshot of my user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brf0I.png)

Comment: *I tried to use Core Audio.NET but it lowers all the main volume.* -- Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: There is a `CoreWebView2.IsMuted` property you can use to mute or unmute all audio from the corresponding CoreWebView2. It doesn't affect the system volume mixer though.